# Return false from Function within function - Javascript Form Validation

Tags: javascript, forms

I made a function which validates a form and works fine but I now want to break it down into 3 separate functions.

I now have a function which is called by the form being submitted which declares some arrays and runs the three functions. When it was all one big function the various if statements that found errors would return false; which would then go back to the form and stop it sending.

However now that I've got functions within a function I can't figure out how to get that message 'false' back to the form.

Below is the function called by the form submit button followed by the main function it calls. 
I tried creating an empty variable which is returned instead of false which is then is assigned the value false by the validateSignup function but it didn't work.

```
function validateSignup()
{
 // Declaring Arrays (deleted array contents)
 var errorSpansArray=[whatever];   
 var regexErrorArray=[whatever];
 var regexArray=[whatever];

validateText(0,6,errorSpansArray, regexErrorArray, regexArray);
passMatch();
genderCountryCheck()  
}

function validateText(formNumber, numberElements, errorSpansArrayName, regexErrorArrayName, regexArrayName)
 {              
                     for (x = 0; x<numberElements; x++)
                   {
                   var spanName = errorSpansArrayName[x];
                   var textError = document.getElementById(spanName);
                   var y=document.forms[formNumber].elements[x];
                   if (!y.value)
                   {           
                    errorMessage(0,spanName,x);
                   return false;
                   }
                   if(!regexArrayName[x].test(y.value)){  
                   textError.innerHTML = regexErrorArrayName[x];
                   return false;

                   }
               }
```

UPDATE:
Thanks for your responses. I have found a solution that seems to work for me.

```
 function validateSignup()
 {
 // Declaring Arrays (deleted array contents)
 var errorSpansArray=[whatever];   
 var regexErrorArray=[whatever];
 var regexArray=[whatever];

var returnValidateText=validateText(0,6,errorSpansArray, regexErrorArray, regexArray);
var returnPassMatch = passMatch();
var returnGenderCountry = genderCountryCheck();

if (returnValidateText || returnPassMatch || returnGenderCountry === false)
    {
    return false;            
    }
    else{
    return true;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call the function it returns a value

```
   var formIsValid = function validateText(....)
```

should do the trick.

```
function validateSignup()
{
     // Declaring Arrays (deleted array contents)
     var errorSpansArray=[whatever];   
     var regexErrorArray=[whatever];
     var regexArray=[whatever];

     var formIsValid = false;

    formIsValid = validateText(0,6,errorSpansArray, regexErrorArray, regexArray);
    formIsValid = passMatch();
    formIsValid = genderCountryCheck()  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to just check the individual function returns directly and return based on that

```
if (!validateText(0,6,errorSpansArray, regexErrorArray, regexArray)) {
  return false;
}
if (!passMatch()) {
  return false;
}    
if (!genderCountryCheck()) { 
  return false;
}
```

Although it's shorter to use a single conditional

```
return
  validateText(0,6,errorSpansArray, regexErrorArray, regexArray) &&
  passMatch() &&
  genderCountryCheck();
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript return false means false will be returned as value where the method is called. So you need something like

```
If(validateText()){
    return true;
}
```

And similarly rest of the code.